# How to apply rotation to a body in Bullet Physics Engine?

Tags: rotation, physics-engine, bullet, bulletphysics

I have rotation values (roll, pitch, yaw). I would like to apply that rotation to a body, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @felipemaia - I'm using the Bullet Physics Engine for 3D rigid body collision detection, I'm not trying to manipulate ballistic trajectories, all I need is to rotate a body lets say a box with the provided rotation values

Comment: Yup. Agreed. Stupidy is indeed priceless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to directly set the world transform for a rigid body, either through a motion state or by direct setting. To get a transform from roll, pitch, and yaw, you could use:

```
btRigidBody * rigidBody = //...
btTransform tr;
tr.setIdentity();
btQuaternion quat;
quat.setEuler(yaw,pitch,roll); //or quat.setEulerZYX depending on the ordering you want
tr.setRotation(quat);

rigidBody->setCenterOfMassTransform(tr);
```

Comment: Is this transformation saved when the world is saved to a .bullet file by using btDefaultSerializer?

Comment: @rraallvv I would definitely expect the transforms for the rigid body would be serialized, so unless I'm missing something (which is possible, it's been a while since I worked with bullet), yes.